# How to use a formula where the range is always different

Tags: vba, excel

how can use a formula on a report where the range is always different. for example i want to multiply column A and column B. so i would like to write a code where i could multiply A*B and expand the formula (or use autofill) all the way to the last row. and the biggest challenge is that is has to be written in a way where everytime i run this macro, column A and column and B will have different amount of rows (Column A&B will always equal the amount of rows). example i run this macro today with 300 rows, and the next time i run it i will have 500 rows.

Comment: What have you tried - post your code?

Comment: So this is what I have but its not really working.  (Dim LastRow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
     
    Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Formula = "=A2*B2"
     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True)

Comment: Please add to your original post in code tags so it's readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Range.AutoFill` method.

```
Sub FillColumnC()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("C2").Formula = "=A2*B2"
    Range("C2").AutoFill Range("C2:C" & LastRow)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Before:

```
  ___A___B___C
1|            
2|   2   3    
3|   3   6    
4|   4   8    
5|   5   1    
6|   6   2    
7|   7   9
```

After:

```
  ___A___B___C
1|            
2|   2   3   6
3|   3   6  18
4|   4   8  32
5|   5   1   5
6|   6   2  12
7|   7   9  63
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this...

```
Sub FormulaInDynamicRange()
Dim LR As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("C2:C" & LR).Formula = "=A2*B2"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```